# Add items to an array without duplicates with using Map object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to add new values to an array without duplicates.

I'm using Map object to hold the previous array and trying to filter the new array

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const res = () => {
        const map1 = new Map(
            arr.map(obj => {
                return [obj.id, obj];
            })
        );

        setItems([map1, ...data.result.filter(x => x.id !== map1.forEach((val, key) => key))]);
    };
```

How to accomplish this iteration successfully? Are there other ways with using Map object that would be better in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to accomplish this iteration successfully?

To test map membership you should not *iterate* the map. The advantage of a map is that you can check for membership with `has`. Also, you should not include the map as the first element of the new array, but spread the original `arr` (or the values of the map):

```
setItems([...arr, ...data.result.filter(x => !map1.has(x.id)]);
```

> Are there other ways with using Map object that would be better in this case?

You could first join the new data to the array and *then* extract the unique values from it via a Map:

```
const res = () => {
    const map1 = new Map(
        data.result.concat(arr).map(obj => {
            return [obj.id, obj];
        })
    );

    setItems([...map1.values()]);
};
```

Note that `data.result` is put in *front* of `arr` so to ensure that the *existing* value has precedence when there is a duplicate. If you prefer that the new value would need to overwrite the previous value for the same `id`, then reverse that order. If you want the old value to remain, *and* you want the really new elements to occur at the *end* of the array, then do:

```
        arr.concat(data.result, arr).map(obj => {
            // ...etc
```